# Assistance with SELECT and COUNT

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a MySQL query to extract a distinct list of UUID's along with a count of the occurrences. Additionally, these counts needs to be grouped with certain status codes that I pass through in a WHERE clause.

I've tried a combination of GROUP BY and COUNT keywords but I cant seem to get the output I need.

I've tried the following SQL statement but I didn't get the correct results

```
SELECT DISTINCT distribution_id, count(distribution_id), status_id from outbound where status_id in (52, 41, 42)
```

The output numbers are incorrect and I don't know what I'm missing in the query. I need a list of the UUID's, the amount of times they occur and what status_id that count relates to.

Comment: Can you give sample data set and sample output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT distribution_id, count(distribution_id), status_id 
from outbound 
where status_id in (52, 41, 42)
GROUP BY distribution_id,status_id
```

GROUP BY operation can help..

Comment: The `DISTINCT` isn't need with `GROUP BY`. You should get the same result with and without `DISTINCT`.

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple. I'm new to SQL and I didn't know you could use a GROUP BY on more than one column. It makes sense now. Does a DISTINCT slow a query down at all?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch edited answer.. thanks for pointing out.. just a case of Copy paste..